# Is there any quick way to delete the standard emails trash files.

Tags: email

I have had a Galaxy S3 for some 3 years and I have recently noticed that I have in excess of 45,000 emails in the standard email's trash folder.

I have tried selecting the trash folder and then using the "delete all" option but the speed of deletes is staggeringly slow, one every five to ten seconds.

It is synchronised with an Office365 account, and I have checked on the server side to see if the same folder exists but it doesn't, it is only on the phone. (Note that this is the standard email app, it is not Gmail or anything similar).

Is there some quick way to empty the email trash folder, either through a file app, or a third party app?

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that your phone's name for certain specialized folders, such as trash, differs from what Office 365 will call it. In Office 365's web interface, and Outlook, the folder is named Deleted Items, and they are kept in sync with your phone's comparable Trash folder. So look there to see the correlation. And yes, deleting from your phone will be dramatically slower than deleting from your computer or the web, the latter being fastest as it's connected directly to the server.

Comment: Thanks TurboFool, the only folders I have through the server side of office 365 are Inbox, draft, sent items, deleted items and junk e-mail. Only inbox and sent items have files, the other folders are empty. This makes sense because I usually delete things off my phone once I have read them knowing that there is a copy on the server.

Comment: That doesn't make sense, though, because if you're using Office 365 it synchronizes between your phone and the server. You can't delete an email on your phone and it still be safe on the server. Only Blackberry does that. Any other enterprise solution is a 2-way sync. Any change you make in one place, reading, deleting, moving, goes to the other one.

Comment: I have the server/incoming settings "delete email from server" set to never. This allows me to delete the email from my phone but leave it on my server. This is what I want as I use my phone primarily to check my emails, I use my laptop as my primary email device. While I am away from my laptop I scan my email, when I get back to my laptop I quickly delete the emails that I don't want and retain the emails I do. The mobile therefore has a separate trash folder of email I have deleted off the phone.

Comment: Well, that's what's preventing you from being able to do that easily. Office 365 wasn't really designed with that concept in mind, and it throws things off pretty heavily. No, there are no third-party utilities to empty this folder for you, as it's a proprietary closed database in Samsung's app.